# Is app.use best practice for handling form data in express?

Tags: node.js, forms, express, routes, query-string

I have been teaching myself node to build my first app and had a question around best practice when it comes to routing in express. Apologies, I couldn't find this answered elsewhere.

Originally, I was using javascript on the front end to dynamically create a query string and then accessing the query parameters in app.use. It then occured to me that I could use a form and POST method to remove some of the complexity and keep the URL clean (i.e avoiding ?allergen=nuts&allergen=milk or ?allergen=nuts,milk).

After struggling, I realised app.use would allow me to capture the form input on Page 1 (lets call this form.html) and then display it on Page 2 (say details.html). Is this best practice or should I be doing this another way? I would set it up so /details would redirect to /form if there was no data.

Please note that I have massively oversimplified the code here, I will be validating the data and then using it to return another value from a JSON file (using canvas to build a custom image based on user input).

**HTML form (using pug)**

```
  <form action="/details" method="post">  
      <input type="checkbox" name="allergen" value="shellfish">
      <label for="shellfish"> Shellfish</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="allergen" value="peanut">
      <label for="peanut"> Peanut</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="allergen" value="milk">
      <label for="milk"> Milk</label>

      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

**Backend (using express)**

```
app.use('/details', (req, res, next) => {
    const allergen = req.body.allergen
    res.render('details', {
        allergen
    });
})
```